# Grails/GORM "in" criteria

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria, grails-orm

Is it possible to do an "in" criteria using the GORM criteria. I'm looking for the equivalent of the following SQL

```
select * from Person where age in (20,21,22);
```

If it was possible I guess the syntax would be something like:

```
def results = Person.withCriteria {
    in "age", [20, 21, 22]
}
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Grails [createCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html) documentation includes an example of using the `in` clause:

```
'in'("holderAge",[18..65]) 
or not{'in'("holderAge",[18..65])}
```

The documentation includes this note:

> Note: 'in' is a groovy reserve word, so it must be escaped by quotes.

Answer (score 4):

Yep, you have it almost exactly right.  Just change `in` to `'in'`, since `in` is a keyword in groovy.