# Grails/GORM “in” criteria enum array

Tags: grails, enums, grails-orm

What is the syntax for GORM withCriteira clause for query data that is an array of enums?

I can see how a static in clause is used with the GORM query criteria
( reference [grails-gorm-in-criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7773741/grails-gorm-in-criteria) )

```
Person.withCriteria {
    'in'("holderAge", [18..65] )
}
```

But what is the syntax for passing the data range into the clause using an array of enums?

```
enum ColorType {
  RED(1),
  BLUE(2)
}

def selectedColorTypes = [ ColorType.RED, ColorType.BLUE ]

class MyClass {
  static hasMany [ colors: colorTypes ]
  ...
}

myList = MyClass.withCriteria {
  'in' ( 'colors', selectedColorTypes )
}
```

This produces the error "Missing IN or OUT parameter at index :: 1"

What is the correct way of passing selectedColorTypes into the withCriteria?

Comment: Your hasMany should be colors: ColorType and not colors: colorTypes

Comment: I second @cantoni, you should have `static hasMany = [colors: ColorType ]` instead.